# How to Add OnItemListener for each row of Android customListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

I have Created a custom List View and i want to add a onItemClick Listener for each row but don't know how to do it without any problem,
Here is the code.  I have tried to do this with by Manually creating a seperate object of ListView and then adding OnitemClick Listener but it does not work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.saadreviews.health_plus.Calories_Activity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtv_calories"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text="Total Calories = "
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textColor="#006600"
/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtv_calories"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/line" />

 <ListView
     android:id="@android:id/list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="317dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
     android:background="@drawable/bg_list" >

</ListView>

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/bttn_reset"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:onClick="reset"
     android:background="@drawable/custom_reset" />
```

Here is the javaFile.

```
public class Calories_Activity extends ListActivity {

ListView lv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_calories);
this.getActionBar().hide();
setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView_food, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food)));

setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView_calories,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.calories)));

    }

    public void reset(View view)
{
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
            "Reset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food);
            String[] calo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.calories);

            ImageView iv= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_food);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView_calories);

            tv.setText(items[position]);
            tv1.setText(calo[position]);

            if(items[position].equals("Apple"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Burger"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.burger);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Mango"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mango);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Orange"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Pizza"))
            {
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pizza);
            }


            return row;
        }



    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calories_, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i2 = new Intent(Calories_Activity.this, Father_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i2);

    }

}
```

Comment: can you show me your raw layout file ? list_item layout ?

Comment: Here is the code, Please help me to add onitemclick listener. Just Toast the name of item.     http://snk.to/f-ct3aoijt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can do iv..setonclickListener(new OnClicklisten);//click event on image..or

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clciked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But sometimes setonitemclick doesnot work in Main class so u need to add listen in adapter class

Comment: Here is the code, Please help me to add onitemclick listener. Just Toast the name of item.

Comment: Here is the code, Please help me to add onitemclick listener. Just Toast the name of item.     http://snk.to/f-ct3aoijt

Comment: have you solved your problem?? @MeharSaadAhsanJhawari

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onListItemClick` in  `Calories_Activity`. Based on position you can do what is necessary

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)

Added in API level 1
This method will be called when an item in the list is selected. Subclasses should override. Subclasses can call getListView().getItemAtPosition(position) if they need to access the data associated with the selected item.

Parameters
l   The ListView where the click happened
v   The view that was clicked within the ListView
position    The position of the view in the list
id  The row id of the item that was clicked
```

Comment: Here is the code, Please help me to add onitemclick listener. Just Toast the name of item.     http://snk.to/f-ct3aoijt

Comment: @MeharSaadAhsanJhawari tell us what is wrong. What you have tried

Comment: I tried to add onitemclick listener (for Example, Show toast on clicked item with its name) but the app crashed when i open list view activity (Calories)

Comment: @MeharSaadAhsanJhawari post the relevant code and stacktrace

Comment: It is the same Android project in which i already created a custom listview but i am unable to implements an onItemClick listener

Comment: @MeharSaadAhsanJhawari a crash right!. post the stacktrace without which its not possible to answer further

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `ListActivity` you can override onListItemClick method:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {}'
```

Comment: Here is the code, Please help me to add onitemclick listener. Just Toast the name of item.       [link]http://snk.to/f-ct3aoijt